# Can not download provisioning profile with a free apple developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode7, provisioning-profile

I signed up for a free apple ID and added my account to Xcode. The `Download All Profiles` doesn't do anything. Is there a way to download these provisioning profiles without paying $99 per year? I am running macOS 10.11 & XCode 7.3 or 8.0 beta 3.

And when trying to set up a new project, I get these errors in the project target's signing section:

`An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.HelloWorld' is not available. Please enter a different string.`

[image]

`No profiles for 'com.example.HelloWorld' were found
Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.example.HelloWorld'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to download these provisioning profiles without paying $99 per year?

No. You cannot "download" anything with just the free Apple ID. You have no access to the Member Center. You simply get the development identity and simple automatically development profiles — and you already have them, though you don't seem to realize it. You are entitled to run an app on your device already.

The rest of your problem is merely that you're not using a real bundle ID. Name your apple's bundle ID uniquely, after yourself, e.g. `difool.john.myCoolApp`, and all will be well. Just attach your device to your computer via USB and run on it. That's what the free ID entitles you to do.

Comment: The bundle identifier set to lastname.firstname fixed it. I couldn't find any mention of this anywhere. I may have missed that part. Thanks a lot.